# Get screen size in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, mobile

In a servlet I'm running on GAE, I'm trying to get the screen width in pixels of the device being used so that I can dynamically redirect the user to either the desktop or mobile jsp page. I first tried using the `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` but receieved the error message: `java.awt.Toolkit is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment`. For now, I'm running the screen check in a jsp page using  javascript but I'd like to move it to the servlets.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move it to the servlets. The server is not aware of the user's screen or any details besides user-agent and what Javascript provides. You'll need to use Javascript and pass around the screen size in a cookie or in the requests.

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
```

being run on GAE is not applicable as we don't care about GAE's screen which is nonexistent anyway.